# TypeORM migration:generate either doesn't work or outputs to root directory

Tags: typeorm

So I have the following folder structure

```
project
 ┣ dist
 ┃ ┗ datasources
 ┃ ┃ ┗ datasource.js
 ┃ ┗ entities
 ┃ ┗ migrations
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ datasources
 ┃ ┃ ┗ datasource.ts
 ┃ ┣ entities
 ┃ ┃ ┗ User.ts
 ┃ ┗ migrations
 ┗ package.json
```

And my `package.json` file.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "typeorm:cli": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -d dist/datasources/datasource.js",
    "migration:generate": "npm run typeorm:cli -- migration:generate",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ....
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ....
    "typeorm": "^0.3.6",
  }
}
```

My `src/datasource/datasource.ts` file

```
const localDs = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  logging: false,
  synchronize: false,
  entities: [path.join(__dirname, '../entities/**/*{.ts,.js}')],
  migrations: [path.join(__dirname, '../migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}')],
  extra: {
    charset: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  },
});
```

When I run

```
yarn migration:generate "BaseMigration"
```

It runs the migration fine, but it outputs the file in the root directory (alongside `package.json` and not in `src/migrations`

I have tried to update the `migration:generate` script to be

```
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm:cli -- migration:generate -d src/migrations",
```

And I get the following error

```
Error during migration generation:
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array
```

Also tried

```
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm:cli -- migration:generate -d src/migrations -n",
```

And I get the following error

```
Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

So how do I add the migration generation into my `.src/migrations` file. I haven't used TypeORM since a previous version where I feel like I could do this?

I've copied dozens of `package.json` files from youtube videos and from other github repos and nothing seems to work. Any ideas? Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this.
in package.json

```
{
   scripts: {
    "typeorm:cli": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -d src/config/data-source.ts",
    "migration:generate": "yarn run typeorm:cli migration:generate",
 }
}
```

then in terminal

```
yarn run migration:generate src/migrations/newMigrationName
```

"npm run [scriptName] -- [options]" syntax should work fine too.